# Fire a jQuery when based on where an element WOULD be

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I suspect this is very simple, but I haven't had much luck finding an answer.

I want to use jQuery to slowly remove an element when a user hovers over it, and then put it back when the user moves their mouse away from where the element WAS.  Right now, the act of removing the element immediately fires the put it back event, and I don't want it to.  Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery?

```
    $("#id").hover(function(){
    $(this).hide("slow");
    });

    $("#id").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#id1').show("slow");
    });
```

I'm sure you could use CSS to make it invisible, and remove it from regular document flow, etc, etc, but I'm wondering if there's not an easier way.

Comment: I suggest you abandon hide/show and instead animate opacity down to zero. Now the user won't see it, but it still exists for mouse events. Remember that rollovers don't work so good on mobile.

Comment: @spender code added.  unfortunately, it cant just be invisible, i need the stuff below it to move up

Comment: Why do you need it to "move up"? So something underneath can receive events?

Comment: @spender no, just a design requirement for how the page needs to look when the element is hidden

Comment: So, I think your only option is to hide AND capture the bounds of the element ( relative to the parent) at mouseenter, then to check if you've escaped those bounds on mousemove of the parent... if you have, show.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or plunkr with all markup etc needed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can toggle opacity and get the same results youre looking for:

```
$("#id").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).animate({opacity:0});
});

$("#id").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).animate({opacity:1});
});
```